# How does map() function work inside Lambda functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can someone please explain what is actually going on in aggfunc here -

```
df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status', index=['Credit_History'],
               aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())
```

Thank you

Comment: It works the same as in any function... Although that is not the built-in `map` function, that is a method being accessed on the argument to the lambda function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Looks like [`pandas.Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Comment: I was confusing this with built-in map, this is actually pandas.Series.map. Thank you @Christian Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example should illustrate what's happening. The `Loan_Status` values are aggregated by `Credit_History` according to the logic "add up number of Y's and divide by total number of observations".

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Y', 'A'], ['N', 'B'], ['Y', 'C'], ['N', 'A'], ['Y', 'C']],
                  columns=['Loan_Status', 'Credit_History'])

df.pivot_table(values='Loan_Status', index=['Credit_History'],
               aggfunc=lambda x: x.map({'Y':1,'N':0}).mean())

#                 Loan_Status
# Credit_History             
# A                       0.5
# B                       0.0
# C                       1.0
```